# How can I apply a once function when using buefy's dialog in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently using buefy's dialog confirm.

```
  methods: {

    async saveButton () {
        var self = this
        this.$dialog.confirm({
          message: 'SAVE',
          canCancel: ['escape', 'button'],
          cancelText: 'CANCEL',
          confirmText: 'OK',
          onConfirm: function () {
            self.saveAPI()
          },
          onCancel: function () {
          }
        })
     },
    async saveAPI() {
      try {
        let data = await API.saveAPI
        return data
      } catch (error) {
      }
    }
  }
```

When the confirm window is activated, if you enter the enter key twice quickly, it is being saved twice.
In the case of the confirmation window that I created myself, I used "@keyup.enter.once" provided by vue js.

How can I make buefy's confirm window work only once?

I checked the Properties API provided by buefy, but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean variable to store current execution state. And  then check the state before sending API request in your "saveAPI".

**For Example:**

```
data() {
  return {
    isExecuting: false,
  }
},
methods: {
  async saveButton () {
      var self = this
      this.$dialog.confirm({
        message: 'SAVE',
        canCancel: ['escape', 'button'],
        cancelText: 'CANCEL',
        confirmText: 'OK',
        onConfirm: function () {
          self.saveAPI()
        },
        onCancel: function () {
        }
      })
    },
  async saveAPI() {
    if (this.isExecuting) {
      return;
    }
    this.isExecuting = true;
    try {
      let data = await API.saveAPI
      return data
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
      this.isExecuting = false;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Also as another solution you can try to add ".once" modifier to a Save Button's @click event handler, but you didn't show your template so I don't quite sure about this way.

```
@click.once="saveButton"
```

Check this please maybe it will be helpful - https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers